# How do I root Samsung Galaxy Tab? (Verizon)

Tags: rooting, samsung-galaxy-tab

I need to install an app which requires root on my Samsung Galaxy tab(Verison).  How can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

I have not attempted this myself, but here are the steps that I found and seems pretty close to how I rooted my Samsung Galaxy S.

**I am not responsible for any issues that arise from following these steps, including, but not limited to your device spontaneously bursting in to flames. I suggest you do additional research and see what others say about using the tools below and read *EVERYTHING TWICE* before doing it. And follow the instructions step-by-step.**

1. The firsts step is to make sure that you have KIES installed on your computer.
2. Now download SuperOneClick Root App [from here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=803682) and save it on your desktop.
3. Once this is done, turn your Samsung Galaxy Tab on and connect it with your computer. Make sure that you have USB debugging mode disabled and sync with KIES.
4. Now disconnect Galaxy Tab from computer and enable USB Debugging mode. You can enable the USB debugging mode by Settings>Applications>Development>USB Debugging.
5. Now reconnect your tab again to your PC and tap the Home button so that your Tab loses sync connection with KIES.
6. Once done, launch SuperOneClick.exe and click on root. Please wait for 5 to 10 minutes while the application roots your Galaxy Tab.